# Get canvas object position and move to canvas touch position in HTML 5 / JS

Tags: javascript, html, animation, position, move

I am new to HTML 5 and JS for iPhone. In my application, I was succeeded to get touch points from the `canvas` by the following code(this is inside my `game.js` class):

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", mouseClickEvent, false);
function mouseClickEvent(e) {
  alert("Clicked x= "+e.layerX+" and clicked y= "+e.layerY);
}
```

and I am displaying an object (`hole`) from the `game.js` class as:

```
var hole = new Image();
hole.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(hole,135,215,50,50);
}
hole.src = 'images/hole.png';
```

Now what I need is to:

**1) Move the `hole` object to the touched position (like animating/moveto).**

**2) Add a click listener to the hole (I tried `canvas.addEventListener`, but not worked).**

I've searched a lot. But not able to find a proper solution :(

Some tutorials said to: remove and redraw the object to move it. But I've several images on my screen, with different shapes.

Pls, pls help me to solve this...

Answer (score 1):

Your touch events can be done like this:

```
var hole = {x: 0, y: 0};

var touchEvents = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.targetTouches) e = e.targetTouches[0]; // since i like to test with a mouse, but still have it work with touch devices.
    hole.x=e.clientX;
    hole.y=e.clientY;
};

canvas.onmousemove=touchEvents;
canvas.ontouchmove=touchEvents;
canvas.ontouchstart=touchEvents;
```

This was quickly converted from my js1k entry, the variable names are short, but maybe you can get a few hints: http://jsfiddle.net/9J25N/